# Add only a specific folder to git submodule

Tags: git, git-submodules

I am currently working in a big project that uses a lot of external libraries that are git repositories themselves and need to be added as git submodules.

The problem is that those libraries are not very specific and might include a lot of subdirectories of which I only need one or a few. Example:

Parent repository

1. subdirectory 1
2. subdirectory 2
3. subdirectory 3
4. subdirectory 4
5. subdirectory 5
6. ... so on

All the subdirectories are quite heavy so I don't want to include them unnecesarily.

I've seen you can [clone only a specific subdirectory](https://terminalroot.com/how-to-clone-only-a-subdirectory-with-git-or-svn/), but I can't figure out how to apply that to a `git submodule add` command.

Any and all help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-submodules%5D+sparse+checkout

Comment: Git does not have this built in: a submodule is a separate repository, and sparse checkout is something you set per repository. If you could mark a submodule as "sparse checkout" (and list the directories to check out), Git could do it for you, but (at least currently) you can't.